# SAML 2.0 assertion response URL for Ping Federate 6.1 service provider

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, federated-identity, pingfederate

A supplier uses Ping Federate for SAML-based single sign-on. I've got some custom SAML 2.0 code which implements a rudimentary identity provider. I'm doing IDP-initiated SSO with URL and HTTP Post. The PF service provider is at https://domain/sp/startSSO.ping. What URL should I be posting my response (assertion) to on the PF server?

I think the official name for the URL I need is the Assertion Consumer Service (ACS) endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://domain/sp/ACS.SAML2

Answer (score 4):

Actually, this value is case sensitive for PingFederate. The value you should use is "/sp/ACS.saml2".